# Getting rid of "Script on a page is not responsive" errors while loading resources

Tags: javascript, html

When my HTML5 app starts, it is loading a bunch of resources, while showing user a non-interactive loading page.

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="loading-screen">Loading, please wait</div>
</div>
```

```
var to_load = resources.length;
var on_load = function() {
  --to_load;
  if (to_load <= 0) {
    document.getElementByID("app").innerHTML = app_html;
    on_everything_loaded();
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; ++i) {
  // Loaded here:
  // -- AJAX requests via xhr
  // -- Image objects
  // -- decodeAudioData, takes most of the time
  resources[i].load(on_load); 
}
```

*Note: this loop does not block browser for a long time. All loading functions used are asynchronous (see the list in comments above).*

Loading process may take a minute or two if machine is slow. Some browsers, especially mobile ones, are prone to display "script on a page is not responsive" error or equivalent — despite the actual page being fully responsive (I even tried to include some interactive elements in the loading screen and coerce user to click on them, didn't help), and almost all heavy work being done inside browser's own resource loading code.

What can I do to prevent these errors from being generated?

Comment: break the most cpu-heavy tasks down and defer them in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)`

Comment: Well, the most cpu-heavy task is decodeAudioData for a large audio file, which is already, I assume, is executed in somewhere in a separate browser thread asynchronously. You suggest that moving decodeAudioData call to a setTimeout would help, right?

Comment: Are you executing it in a WebWorker?  If not, there is no separate browser thread.

Comment: @robertc: But decodeAudioData call does not block the UI... OTOH, it is called from an AJAX xhr callback, may be this is the culprit?